# Is Xcode 4.2 compatible with both OS4 and iOS5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I am developing my app in Xcode 4.2. I would like to know if the app which I'm developing in Xcode 4.2 will work on both iOS4 and iOS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it support for both.
You just need to change you Deployment target to lowest one

Project->Target->summary->Deployment target

change it with lower one

then it will work

Comment: Thanks shivam, I have used MainStoryboard.storyboard in my app which is not available in ios4. Can you please suggest me what should I do now to make my app working on ios4 as well.

Comment: I am really sorry to say that this feature is not supported by ios4.

create this macro on header 
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)

and

YOu may make condition in this way 

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0"))    
    {
}

Comment: Storyboards themselves are NDAd. But no, storyboards are absolutely not compatible with iOS4, the rely on new runtime classes which are not available there

Answer (score 0):

You can declare what iOS versions your app supports in your project 'Info'. Also make sure that you select "NO" for "Build Active Architecture Only" in your project 'Settings'.